# How do I search for questions that have CSS or JavaScript tags?

Tags: support, search

I have tried:

```
[css] or [javascript]
```

but this only gives questions that have either the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag or the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag. It does not give questions containing both tags.

Note: I am not asking about questions with **both** tags. I am looking for questions with either [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and no [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and no [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), or both tags together.

Comment: It does for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2TQS.png. Do you mean you *only* want questions with the css and javascript tags?

Comment: `[css] [javascript]`?

Comment: @PaulRoub Not sure how this is a duplicate of the 2nd question. Just covering all bases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for `[css] or [javascript]` does give questions tagged both [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript); since they're relatively rare, you sometimes have to scroll down and/or navigate to other pages:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### It does not give questions containing both tags.

```
[css] or [javascript]
```

Remove the `or` and search for

```
[css] [javascript]
```